# поиск в List по первым буквам и случайный выбор результата

Tags: java, list, случайные-числа

Есть некий список из слов:

```
List<String> resultPc = cities.stream()
    .filter(item -> item.toString().substring(0,1).equals(inpLastPl))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

такая конструкция прекрасно ищет в потоке списка и сравнивает первые буквы, а `resultPc` получает все причитающиеся ему плюшки и, что потрясающе - все вхождения на заданную букву `inpLastPl`.

Вопрос такой:

> как из всех слов в resultPc выбрать случайно одно и передать
>   переменной?

Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: String resultPc = cities.stream()
            .filter(item->item!=null && !item.isEmpty())
            .filter(item -> item.substring(0,1).equals(inpLastPl))
            .findAny().orElse(null);

Comment: случайное слово в resultPc упадёт?

Comment: смотря что вы понимаете под "случайным". findAny() - не генератор случайных чисел. согласно документации, не гарантировано, какой именно элемент стрима попадет в результат. это просто не специфицировано, следовательно, туда может попасть любой элемент (я думаю, что это можно назвать "случайным"). вместе с тем, это не значит, что для конкретного частного случая в результат будет попадать каждый раз новый элемент. во втором случае можно схитрить и использовать вместо stream parallelStream. это, конечно, не по назначению, но результат будет разный и для частного случая)

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, у String есть startsWith("...").
Во-вторых, можно сделать shuffle, и брать какой либо индекс.